# Calibrating using two color targets?

Tags: colorchecker

I have two color targets, one is the x-rite Colorchecker Digital SG, the one is CMP Digital Target Studio Edition. While the x-rite one is missing some brighter color patches like pink, the CMP target is also missing darker color like navy blue. They both have color that fill in what the other one is missing. So I thinking to create a super target for calibration by joining both targets together.

Has anyone done this before?

What I'm thinking is to first gather all the color data (XYZ/LAB) of both targets and put them into a cie file. Then take a photo of both target under the same lighting condition and then stitch them together in photoshop. And then load the stitch image and the data file into program like 3D LUT Creator and plot them out in a color grid.

Is there a more automatic way to do this? And since the two targets may have similar color patches, how do I know what to throw away as redundant?

Answer (score 1):

I think, generally speaking, if you cover the full gamut and tone curves of what you're profiling you should be mostly OK with only one target.  ICC-style color management is about characterizing how your device renders colors on the whole, instead of the Pantone approach of specifically matching a few individual spot colors perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much benefit IMO.

What you should care about is that the color checker has colors that are representative of the subject you are going to photograph. Because when you color correct for one color it also affects all other colors. I.e. if you calibrate/correct so that a particular red renders as accurately as possible, then other colors will probably be a little less accurate.

What is usually done is to calibrate/correct so that all colors are as close as they can be on average, but none are exact. In this case specific colors in the chart are not really important (unless an automated program is being used).

Comment: I am trying to archive a color chart, so I want my color target to cover as much gamut as possible. I can't rely on interpolation because of a missing hue in the color target when I have 10 shades of that hue to be measured.

Comment: Archiving how; by generating a print? If not, why aren't XYZ measurements adequate? If yes, you have a bunch more issues IMO.

Comment: I'm trying to digitize it. I'll be shooting both targets, join them to create a super target, then use 3D LUT creator to make a matching lut and that lut will be applying to the color chart that I'll be shooting to archive them. The problem I have is that I don't know how to stitch the two targets' data together programmatically.